# How to pass core data into a SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield

I am trying to pass a core data field into a TextField so I can edit it. What am I missing here.  How can I feed userProfile[0].alias ?? "" into $alias so it can be seen and edited in the text field?

```
private var userProfile: FetchedResults<UserProfile>
@State var alias: String = ""


    Section(header: Text("Alias")) {
        Print("\(userProfile[0].alias ?? "")")
        TextField("your online identifier", text: $alias)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Core Data Binding TextFields in DetailView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225849/swiftui-core-data-binding-textfields-in-detailview)

Comment: You are treating you r`FetchedResults<UserProfile>` as if it is an array. It is a random access collection of the fetched entity, but not an array(which is another type of random access collection). You can't address a member of is as `userProfile[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about `userProfile[0]` then here is a possible approach

```
Section(header: Text("Alias")) {
    Print("\(userProfile.first.alias ?? "")")
    TextField("your online identifier", text: $alias, onCommit: {
       guard let profile = userProfile.first else { return }
       profile.alias = alias
       try? viewContext.save()
    })
    .onAppear {
       alias = userProfile.first.alias ?? ""
    }
}
```